# Can anyone help cannot run this unix shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Can anyone help cannot run this unix shell script due to loads of syntax errors within it, i have solved a few but cannot solve a few more i have used google but my searching has not been successful. This main error i am trying to figure out is on line 68 an awk statement

if you can help this would be wonderful and i would be grateful as the deadline for this work is coming ever closer.

```
awk '$1 !~/'$userpassword'/' db > db2
echo "Withdraw Money"
echo -e "Amount: RM\c"
read withdrawAmount # echo . > db4
nawk -F:'/'$idpassword'/{print $3}' db > db5
oldbalance = 'cat db5';
newbalance = 'echo $oldbalance - $withdrawAmount | bc-1'
newrecord = "$idpassword: $username: $newbalance"
echo $newrecord > db3
cat db3 >> db2
cp db2 db
```

the error message is ./test2: line 68: syntax error near unexpected token`'$1 !~/'$userpassword'/'' db > db2

Comment: **always** provide the **error message**. it might not be informative to you (google?) but it is for us...

Comment: come up with a **minimal example**. remove the parts that aren't relevant to your question. (eg: we don't care about those `echo`s and `sleep`s, replace user input with fixed variables, etc.. I hope you get the point). `set -x` is a clever way to see what gets executed and in the same time possibly come up with a minimal example.

Comment: yeah, that awk-statement is wrong. What shell are you using? bash, dash, sh?

Comment: What is your expected output from running `awk '$1 !~/'$userpassword'/' db > db2`?  Provide a small example of your input file (db) and the expected output (db2).

Answer (score 1):

To pass shell variables into awk, use the `-v` option:

```
awk -v patt="$userpassword" '$1 !~ patt' db > db2
```

Comment: Please read the questions in http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking, especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask